# Using PlaySound to play a wav file

Tags: c, linker, playsound

I'm using windows 7 running visual studio 2010 and writing in Cc.

Here is a snippet of my code. When the condition is met (temperature is higher than high limit) then I want to play a wav file from my computer. I checked around the forums and I copied the same format as a previous poster had i still have the same problem. I get the following errors:

> 1>lab4TemperatureController.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _*imp*_PlaySoundA@12 referenced in function "void __cdecl activateAlarm(int,int)" (?activateAlarm@@YAXHH@Z)
>
> 1>C:\Users\Hassman\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\lab6\lab6TemperatureControlTime\Debug\lab3temperaturesensor.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals

Here are my header files included in my CPP

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "lab4temperatureController.h"
#include <conio.h>
#include "console.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
```

here is my function that calls playsound

```
void activateAlarm(int channelID, temperature_t temperature)
{
    int key = 0;

    if ((temperatureChannel[channelID].currentTemperature > temperatureChannel[channelID].highLimit) | (temperatureChannel[channelID].currentTemperature < temperatureChannel[channelID].lowLimit))
        PlaySound(TEXT("C:\\Users\\Hassman\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2010\\Projects\\lab6\\lab6TemperatureControlTime\\lab3temperaturesensor\\untitled"),NULL,SND_FILENAME);
    sensorLog();
    if (_kbhit())
        key = _getch();         
    if ((key == 'P') | (key == 'p'))
    {
        silenceBeep();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like you're forgetting to link your object file with the library that contains the implementation of that function while generating the executable output file.

According to [The MSDN Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd743680%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), using `PlaySound` requires linking with `Winmm.lib`.